# add esc sequence with sed ( \033[K)

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I want to add an escape (tty control) at the end of each line.

`sed '/s/$/foo/g'` appends `foo` to the end of the line.
I want to append `esc[K` to the end of line (erase to end of line)
I've tried

```
sed 's/$/\033[K/g'
sed 's/$/\\033[K/g'
sed 's/$/\e[K/g'
sed 's/$/\\e[K/g'
```

Neither produces an escape-character, just prints what I enter.

How can I get an escape-character  in sed?

Comment: `bash` or some other shell?

Comment: bash.
I can echo -e \\033[H; at the top of the bash script to move the cursor home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try an escaped string

```
sed $'s/$/\033[K/g'
```

The `$'…'` tells the shell to handle escapes inside what is otherwise a literal single-quoted string

A better approach could be to append the *Clear to EOL* only if you're writing to a terminal:

```
test -t 1 && el=$(tput el)
…
sed 's/$/'"$el/"
```

Notice I switch quoting styles part way through - this helps the `$` remain as a literal while allowing `$el` to be expanded to its value (if any). We could also have used `"s/\$/$el/"`